# Why does my code stops working when I add this? Simple JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#insert_image').click(function(){
    $('#image').attr("src", "img/julia1.jpg");
});
```

First block of code stops working when I add the following:

```
$('#insert_paragraph').click(function(){
    var text = $('#paragraph').val();
    $('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>'text'</p>');
});
```

The first block of code has nothing to do with the second, so why does it stop working? Also on the second block of code I'm trying to create a text are on which you can type a paragraph and when you click a button next to it, it replaces the textarea with a paragraph on the page.

Comment: `replaceWith('<p>'+text+'</p>');`

Comment: Can you post the HTML and create a jsFiddle?

Comment: That is invalid Javascript syntax.

Comment: .val() is only valid for input types.

Comment: Time to learn about the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: You need to check the JavaScript console in order to find syntax error.

Comment: If in chrome, just hit F12, switch to Console tab, and you can even click the line numbers on the errors to jump to the error location.

Comment: 5 answers and counting......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make these changes:

```
$('#insert_paragraph').click(function(){
    var text = $('#paragraph').val(); //if input, use .val(), otherwise use .text() or .html()
    $('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>' + text + '</p>');
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since you are using `textarea`, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('#insert_paragraph').click(function(){
    var text = $('#paragraph').val(); 
    $('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>' + text + '</p>');
});
```

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/d99wF/3/

Comment: the + fixed the problem, however if I change .val() for either text() or html() the button doesnt do anything anymore.

Comment: @ManuelMedina oh ok, since I did not see your HTML, I assumed `#paragraph` was a `<p>`.  If it is an `input`, use `.val()`. Otherwise, use `.text()` or `.html()`. Also feel free to post your HTML and I will make the necessary changes.

Comment: If I used a <p> tag to change the html of the page it wouldn't be semantically correct.

Comment: Wait so you are trying to nest `<p>`s? Sorry can you post your HTML so I can see what you're trying to go for?

Comment: no, Im replacing a <textarea> with a <p>

Comment: @ManuelMedina oh! ok made edit!

Answer (score 2):

Because `'<p>' text '</p>'` should be `'<p>' + text + '</p>'`

The concatenation in javascript is done using `+` ;

Answer (score 1):

syntax error in:

```
$('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>'text'</p>');
```

try this

```
$('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>' + text + '</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `+` sign in :

```
 $('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>'+text+'</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Pay Attention:**

Adding one string to another is done by the `+` char.

Try this code instead:

```
$('#insert_paragraph').click(function(){
    var text = $('#paragraph').val();
    $('#paragraph').replaceWith('<p>'+text+'</p>');
});
```